# My User Control inside a DataGrid keep reseting

Tags: c#, wpf, xml

I'm new to WPF, so maybe I'm doing something really stupid. But..
Also is my first question here.

I made a custom ProgressBar UserControl to use inside a DataGrid.
All look to work fine except that every time the DataGrid refresh (reordering a column) the UserControl resets, all properties and dependency properties change to their default values and the constructor is called again. Look like my control is destroyed and recreated on every DataGrid's refresh.

Anyway to avoid that behavior?

I need to keep the changes history.
edit:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Progress" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:SegmentedProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SegmentedProgressCustomUpdate="{Binding SegmentedProgressCustomUpdate}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Please add the code which shows the UserControl inside the DataGrid

Comment: How do you "refresh" the DataGrid?

Comment: I just call dtgDevices.Items.Refresh();

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if the DataGrid is data binding again.  That would cause the rows to potentially get recreated and, therefore, the user control to get reset. That said, if you are pulling the progress bar off of some external data, you could dynamically set all of the properties for the progress bar control in the row created event.